# Understanding of getpeername function

Tags: c, sockets, unix, networking

I am reading [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html) documentation:

```
int getpeername(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

> **getpeername()** returns the address of the peer connected to the socket
>   sockfd

**Questions**:

1. If I am on the server machine and I have the "server" and many "clients" connections to sockfd what address will it return?
2. What does `peer` mean in this context?

Answer (score 0):

The "peer" is the socket your socket is connected to.

If you use it on a server socket, I would assume it returns an error. I have not tested this. If you use it on one of your many client connection sockets, it returns the address of that client.

Answer (score 0):

> If I am on the server machine and I have the "server" and many "clients" connections to sockfd what address will it return?

- when you connect a server socket with many clients, these connections are handled separately, so each time a connection is opened or a file descriptor is active, the socketfd of that client socket will be returned.
- The simple way to handle multiple clients would be to spawn new thread for every new client connected to the server. This method is strongly not Highly recommended if you don't know how to code, debug and maintain multi-threads. OR, maybe as it suggested [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-cc-handling-multiple-clients-on-server-without-multi-threading/), you can use some linux functions to handle these connections.

> What does peer mean in this context?

- a peer is whatever device connected to your device directly, you can find it on [techterms](https://techterms.com/definition/p2p).